# Return Observable from ngrx store pipe selector

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, rxjs-observables

I have a ngrx store selector:

```
export const selectActivePracticeUsersListSnapshot = pipe(
  select(selectPracticeUsersList),
  filter((users) => !!users),
  take(1),
  map((users) => users.filter((user) => user.active))
);
```

I have a service that is injected into multiple components that contains the following method:

```
public getTeamMembersWithAccess(permission: string): string[] {
  let flagAvatars: string[];
  this.store.dispatch(loadUsers());
  this.store.pipe(selectActivePracticeUsersListSnapshot).subscribe((activePracticeUsers) => {
    flagAvatars = activePracticeUsers.reduce((teamMembers, activeUser) => {
      if (!!activeUser.permissions[permission]) {
        const { firstName, lastName } = activeUser;
        return [...teamMembers, `${firstName} ${lastName}`];
      }
      return teamMembers;
    }, []);
  });
  return flagAvatars;
}
```

I call this from my component thusly:

```
constructor(private helperService: HelperService) {
  const flagAvatars = this.helperService.getTeamMembersWithAccess('AdminPage');
}
```

My problem is that the service method returns undefined because of the *let flagAvatars: string[];* before the subscription to the store selector returns as it is waiting for the dispatch of *loadUsers()* to complete. I know I need to change the *getTeamMembersWithAccess()* method to return an *Observable<string[]>* somehow, but I'm not sure how to write this. I've tried multiple things but can't get it right. Pretty sure I need to use a map instead of a subscribe, but just can't figure out how to write that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're completely right with your statement, I will assist you in making it concrete.

Try this:

Service:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
......
public getTeamMembersWithAccess(permission: string): Observable<string[]> {
  this.store.dispatch(loadUsers());
  this.store.pipe(selectActivePracticeUsersListSnapshot).pipe(
   map((activePracticeUsers) => {
    // flagAvatars equals this, so let's just return it right away in the map
    return activePracticeUsers.reduce((teamMembers, activeUser) => {
      if (!!activeUser.permissions[permission]) {
        const { firstName, lastName } = activeUser;
        return [...teamMembers, `${firstName} ${lastName}`];
      }
      return teamMembers;
    }, []);
   });
  )
}
```

To consume it:

```
this.helperService.getTeamMembersWithAccess('AdminPage').subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```